# Bulk batch inserts to MySQL gives GC Overhead and/or Java Heap Space errors

Tags: java, mysql, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am trying to insert around 1.9 Million rows at once as a bulk Batch Insert into MySQL. The code works like a charm with 1.7 Mil or less rows but I get an GC Overhead and/or sometimes Java Heap Space errors for more than 1.8 Mil rows.

Code:

```
    try {
            // triples is of type ArrayList<String>
            String[] tripleToInsert= null;
            for (int i = 0; i < triples.size(); i++) {
                count++;
                tripleToInsert= triples.get(i).split("\\s+");

                /** Insert <s,p,o> into Triples table **/

                preparedStmt.setString(1, tripleToInsert[0].trim());
                preparedStmt.setString(2, tripleToInsert[1].trim());
                preparedStmt.setString(3, tripleToInsert[2].trim());

                preparedStmt.addBatch();
                preparedStmt.clearParameters();

                tripleToInsert=null;
            }


        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            System.out.println("OOM error: IN LOADING TO DB function on loop count: " + count);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

String preEndTime= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println("Preprocessing Ended:" + preEndTime);



        //Insert start time
        String startTime= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println("Insert Started:" + startTime);

        // execute the prepared statement as a batch
        long[] results = preparedStmt.executeLargeBatch();

        System.out.println("Update Count size: "+ results.length);

        //Insert end time
        String endTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println("Insert Completed:" + endTime);
```

Encounters errors:

```
    OOM error: IN LOADING TO DB function on loop count: 1888076
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.toBytesWrapped(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.getBytesWrapped(StringUtils.java:652)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4005)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.loadTriplesByBatches(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:282)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.insertNTriplesToDB(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:137)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.main(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:77)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimeZone.clone(TimeZone.java:738)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.clone(ZoneInfo.java:647)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:625)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(SimpleDateFormat.java:657)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:601)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:580)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.loadTriplesByBatches(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:330)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.insertNTriplesToDB(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:137)
    at LoadNTriplesByScript.main(LoadNTriplesByScript.java:77)
```

Eclipse version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Java heap sizes:
-Xms2048m    -Xmx3072m

I am not sure if this is caused by String manipulation (split() method) or if there is a LIMIT on PreparedStatement addBatch() methods on no. of rows per batch. I have set autoCommit(FALSE) and then commit() after executing the PreparedStatement.

**Note**: I have read numerous articles ad posts on GC Overhead and Java Heap Errors. Any kind of suggestion or pointers as to why this is happening is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a very high probability, you just ran out of memory. The message is misleading as the high GC overhead is usually simple caused by having nothing to collect (all memory is in use).

The reason for batching is avoiding the high per command overhead. Concerning performance, it hardly matters if you use batches of 1000 or 1000000 lines. So try smaller batches.

Maybe also try smaller commits, if your application can live with seeing incomplete data for a while.

Note that you're keeping in memory both the original line in `triples` and the split one in `tripleToInsert`. With 1.8M rows and 3 GB total, you can use less than about 1500 Bytes per row. Consider that a character is two bytes in Java, consider that you're storing it twice and that there's always some overhead, so it could work with maybe < 300 chars per line (just a guess).

You're basically doing it right, it's just that such a huge batch needs a lot of memory. If this is just an import, than you can save some memoryy by clearing the unsplit triples as they get consumed.

Sometimes it's possible to use a build-in CSV import provided by the DB.

Comment: I tried having smaller batches but it wouldn't be efficient for large no. of batches, would it ?? Also, the data is not in a CSV to be directly loaded using LOAD script. So even if i convert to csv and then load it...it would just be a tradeoff between insert time vs loading time. Another thing is that of somehow reduce the row size, there would be less chance of getting GC and Heap errors i think.

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade As I wrote, batching is meant to reduce the per command overhead. Without batches, the overhead is `x`, with a single huge batch, it's `x/1.8e6`, with batches of size 1000, it's `x/1000`. So this is what I'd try first. `+++` Exporting to a CSV is a bit ugly, but it may make sense and it may be the simplest solution. An advantage is keeping your Java busy for the shortest time. `+++` Optimizing the memory consumption would help, but when you data grow a lot, you'll be facing the same problem again.